# How to get msbuild to compile project after custom event

Tags: msbuild

I'm trying to amend the version number in AssemblyInfo.cs in my automated Test build - an MSBuild .proj. I can successfully write whatever I want to AssemblyInfo.cs, but this is not reflected in the project DLL in either the bin or bin/Project/_PublishedWebsites/bin.

I have tried using **InitialTargets**, **BeforeBuild** and **BeforeCompile** in my msbuild .proj but while this amends src/.../Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs it doesn't seem to end up making it to the compile DLL.

Some examples of what I have tried:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" InitialTargets="BeforeCompile" DefaultTargets="FullPublish" ...
```

and/or

```
<Target Name="BeforeCompile"
```

The fuller picture is I want to do the following:

1. Amend the AssemblyInfo with the TFS build version/revision
2. Build/compile the sln
3. Transform the web.config
4. Call node r.js
5. Deploy to our load balanced servers

Individually I've got them all working fine, I'm just lacking a compile project.dll with the correct version number - it always says **1.0.0.0**. I want 1) to before the project is built and 3-5 to be after.

I'm using MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets and Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll if that's of any relevance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupidly this was nothing to do with the targets order. In my Test build I had added the .sln first, then the publish.proj second (which contained the stuff above). So regardless of anything I did in the .proj file, it would always be after the solution had compiled.

The answer was clearly to separate out the .proj into 2 and run them in the correct order.